# Unity3D create iTextSharp PDF in Android

Tags: android, pdf, fonts, unity-game-engine, itext

I am making a report in Unity3D with iTextSharp. When I start app from Unity it creates PDF and works perfect. But when I build App on Android device, I have a problem with creating font. Here is what I do:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "ADOBEARABIC-BOLD_0.OTF"), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, false);
```

As I have seen, the first parameter for font creation is the path to the font. My font is in `/Assets/StreamingAssets/` folder.

When I try to load it with WWW class, it can find it, but when I give just the path to the creator it won't work.

Any idea what should I do? Or is there any other way to create a font that supports Arabic characters?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I have somehow managed to get to the font. First I copy font from `Assets` to the root of the APP:

```
IEnumerator CopyFiles()
    {
        string fromPath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/";
        string toPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/";
        string filesNamesToCopy = "ADOBEARABIC-BOLD_0.OTF";
        WWW www1 = new WWW(fromPath + filesNamesToCopy);
            yield return www1;
        File.WriteAllBytes(toPath + filesNamesToCopy , www1.bytes);
    }
```

And then I make BaseFont:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "ADOBEARABIC-BOLD_0.OTF"), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Now I get new error when try to build on Android device:

> ArgumentException: Encoding name 'windows-1252' not supported
>   Parameter: name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put some DLL files to project folder. Which one depends what encoding you have to use.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/42955/codepage-1252-not-supported-works-in-editor-but-no.html